# Geom_Bar Legends GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like

[image]

I was trying to draw overlapping geom_bars showing number of entries per Submission Date vs Today

```
lag_demonstration  <- ggplot(dataflow ,aes())+
  geom_bar(aes(x = SubmissionDate), fill = "red", alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = today), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.25) +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

This gives the plot overall looking how I want

[image]

But I would like to have a legend/label showing which colour is which type (Submission Date vs Today)

I reshaped the data frame using

```
dataflow_2 <- gather(dataflow,Date,epiday,SubmissionDate:today)
```

So now the data frame looks like
[image]

Then I used a slightly different GGPLOT call

```
    lag_demonstration2  <- ggplot(dataflow_2 ,aes(x = epiday, fill = Date))+
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, position = "dodge") +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

This gets the labels on but the bar chart is less nice to look at
[image]

I've spent a fair amount of time trying to get this to work so am really open to suggestions.

Note that if you remove `position = dodge` from the second version it isn't quite right as it stacks the two forms on top of each other - see plot 3

[image]

Comment: Reshaping from wide to long is the way to go (and the `ggplot2` way). Removing `position = "dodge2"` should do what you are after, no?

Comment: If you remove dodge it is not quite right because then it stacks the bar charts (see extra plot added above)

Comment: Try replacing it with `position = "identity"`. Does that look like what you are looking for?

Comment: please don't post sample data as image - as an established user you should know this... you can always copy your code output as code into the question, instead of images. this makes the question less convoluted. And as a last tip, maybe consider embedding smaller images...